# How do you write to the syswow64 folder in Win10?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to write a basic 'hello world' file to the `SysWow64` folder and nothing traditional seems to allow me to write to that folder.

Windows 10 appears to have a new security model.

1. How do I write a basic 'hello world' file to SysWow64
2. Can someone provide a link to a break down of the new Windows 10 security model for Linux admins?

Comment: I'm not aware of any "new security model", and writing into syswow64 works fine for me - you shouldn't be writing files there, mind you, that's a system folder, but there isn't anything stopping you from doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no new security model in Windows 10, the [current one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) was introduced with Windows Vista in 2006

To create a new file using PowerShell:

```
 "Hello World" | Set-Content $env:systemroot\syswow64\HelloWorld.txt
```

this assumes your user has permissions to write to that directory. In this case you have to be a member of the administrators group and your shell process has to have an integrity level of `High`. This is normally done by selecting `Run as administrator` in the context menu.

Having said that, an administrator has no business creating any new files in that directory.

Comment: Microsoft seems to think that my computer is their computer, but it's not. I enjoy writing to any folder I want to on 'my' computer that I want. The day I cannot 'fully' administrate my own system is the day I fully delete that OS.  It was getting really close to format time for old MS.  Thank you, you save MS for at least one more version!

Comment: syswow64 imports a .jpg but a .exe fails???

Comment: @NIX - I have no problems copying a .exe to syswow64 and execute it from there. How are you doing this? And maybe give us a good reason why you are doing it other than `I want to be the master of my OS`

Comment: antivirus  was the issue.